# How do I get the touchpad working on an Acer Aspire 5332

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 on my Acer Aspire 5332. I now have an issue with my touchpad not working. When I type the command x input list in the terminal here is what comes up:

```
~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ NOVATEK Kensington U+P Keyboard           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ NOVATEK Kensington U+P Keyboard           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I'm not sure what I can do to fix it. If you need any more information, I will be happy to provide.

Comment: I am sure you have, but have you tried restarting the computer since the touchpad has stopped working?

Comment: Yes, that hasn't achieved anything

Comment: Okay sorry to ask such a juvenile question but I try to never make assumptions... :-D